# Adding random fonts to each element of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

Been trying to make it so that each div with the class `.book` gets allocated a random font from an array. This is my code so far

```
var fonts = ['Gloria Hallelujah', 'Sedgwick Ave', 'Gochi Hand', 'Patrick Hand', 'Kalam', 'Rock Salt', 'Neucha', 'Caveat Brush', 'Schoolbell'];
var randomfont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
$(".book").style.fontFamily = randomfont;
```

The error I am getting is:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined`

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `$(".book").css("font-family", randomfont);`

Comment: Please post your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".book")` returns a jquery array.  eg to set the first you would use:

```
$(".book")[0].style.fontFamily =
```

You need to loop through `$(".book")` to get the DOM elements:

```
$(".book").each(function() {
    var randomfont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
    this.style.fontFamily = randomfont; 
});
```

(unless you meant to set them all to the same font, in which case set `randomfont` outside the loop).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to set the fontFamily directly on the jQuery object instead of the DOM element.

Either use jQuery's `css` method or use `get`/*array selector* to retrieve the DOM element.

On the other hand you want to do that on each element, so you need to use `each` like this:

```js
//const fonts = ['Gloria Hallelujah', 'Sedgwick Ave', 'Gochi Hand', 'Patrick Hand', 'Kalam', 'Rock Salt', 'Neucha', 'Caveat Brush', 'Schoolbell'];
const fonts = ['Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Verdana', 'Courier', 'Courier New'];

$('.book').each(function(item) {
  const randomfont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
  this.style.fontFamily = randomfont;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book">Test 1</div>
<div class="book">Test 2</div>
<div class="book">Test 3</div>
<div class="book">Test 4</div>
<div class="book">Test 5</div>
<div class="book">Test 6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help. just call the id using the `document.getElementById('')` and then set the font value.

```
var fonts = ['Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif', 'Sedgwick Ave', ' Helvetica', 'Patrick Hand', 'Kalam', 'Rock Salt', 'Neucha', 'Caveat Brush', 'Schoolbell'];
var randomfont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
alert(randomfont);
var val=document.getElementById("book").style.fontFamily = randomfont;
```

Comment: Won't work as OP want's to set by *class* not by *id*.   The implication is that there are multiple elements to be set and ID should be unique.